# List doesn't show on latex within the tabbing environment

Tags: itemize, tabbing

It's not giving me the list below the first line. I'm unsure how to fix this.

The code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section*{\underline{eeee}}
\vspace{-2mm} 

\begin{tabbing}
dddd \= 2021 \(\qquad\) \= cccc \\

\>\>
\begin{itemize}
\item bbbb 
\item aaaa
\end{itemize}
\\

\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

I want it to take the following form

```
dddd     2021      cccc
                   •    Bbbb
                   •    aaaa
```

where the list is tabbed directly beneath 'cccc'.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: My apologies! I edited it - I do hope it's more clear. @Mensch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using a tabular makes things easier.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
\section*{\underline{eeee}}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}l@{\qquad}l}
ddd & 2021  & ccc\\ 
    &       &\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep} bbb\\
    &       &\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep} aaa
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

**UPDATED** after follow-up question

If instead of bbb you want to insert a long sentence, you have to set the width of the column.

By adding the `array` package it is possible to specify such a column with `m{<width>)`

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}% column type m

\begin{document}
    
\section*{\underline{eeee}}

\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}l@{\qquad}l}
ddd & 2021  & ccc\\ 
    &       &\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep} bbb\\
    &       &\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep} aaa
\end{tabular}\bigskip


\noindent\begin{tabular}{l@{\qquad}l@{\qquad}m{0.3\linewidth}}
    ddd     & 2021  & ccc\\ 
            &       &\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep} A very long sentence a very long sentence a very long sentence\\
            &       &\textbullet\hspace{\labelsep} aaa
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works - thank you! The only issue with this is if I put in a long sentence in place of 'bbb', it carries on off the page. If that makes sense?

Comment: @erika You have to limit the width of the column. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, Simon !